# Verification of $F(m)^{d} \pmod n \equiv m$ with very large inputs, where $F(m)=m^e$

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity, computer-algebra-systems

Does anyone have the computational power to check whether or not

$F(m)^{d} \pmod n \equiv m$, where the values of the variables are found below.

According to Wolfram Alpha, I found the result of the computation $F(m)=m^e \pmod n$, however I don't know how reliable Wolfram is with computations of this size and I am unable to compute $F(m)^d \pmod n \equiv m$ in Wolfram, since the numbers are too large.

```
m=112951412120151619251851615182016118201

n=145906768007583323230186939349070635292401872375357164399581871019873438799005358938369571402670149802121818086292467422828157022922076746906543401224889672472407926969987100581290103199317858753663710862357656510507883714297115637342788911463535102712032765166518411726859837988672111837205085526346618740053

d=89489425009274444368228545921773093919669586065884257445497854456487674839629818390934941973262879616797970608917283679875499331574161113854088813275488110588247193077582527278437906504015680623423550067240042466665654232383502922215493623289472138866445818789127946123407807725702626644091036502372545139713

F(m)= 22759056015886739716909089234835188351754889051525507970444538546831824365432006473081682583255424846673851966695239042380796121790409431507631093425

e=65537
```

Comment: Figured out the formatting. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh that's right. I'll figure something out. Give me a moment.

Comment: And what is $F$?  Fibonacci?

Comment: F is just the function $F(m)=m^e \pmod n$, with input $m$

Comment: If you are looking for something more powerful than W|A and still free to use, consider [Sage](http://sagemath.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Maple, 
$$\eqalign{m^e &\equiv 14178120117339266261904109624890227407523673482786024455164108238811626728989472\cr &1928886528279400665340976615948053755946789302972467196231829204061441862114262
\cr &11704026304276898946101664519229545142128929712389990917298990673103791915511466
\cr &3997141846344255396618911673987467404521083471325973763420396488985050 \mod n}$$
which doesn't match your $F(m)$.

But it is true that $(m^e)^d \equiv m \mod n$.

Comment: I computed $m^e \mod n$ with both [reduce](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/) (which is sometimes slow or crashes when working with large numbers), and with [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) (the interpreter worked just fine and quick, though for even bigger numbers one might prefer to compile the program) and both confirmed the value posted in this answer.